# PostgreSQL complaining about shared memory, but shared memory seems to be OK

Tags: postgresql, schema, memory

I've been performing kind of intensive schema dropping and creating over a PostgreSQL server, but now complains..:

```
WARNING:  out of shared memory
ERROR:  out of shared memory
HINT:  You might need to increase max_locks_per_transaction.
```

But the problem remains if PostgreSQL is just restarted with `service postgresql restart`, I suspect max_locks_per_transaction won't tune nothing.

I am a bit estranged because the troubleshooting lists for this error is not working for me.

**MORE INFO 1409291350:** Some details missing but I keep the core SQL result.

```
postgres=# SELECT version();
PostgreSQL 9.3.5 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2,
 64-bit
```

And:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

Comment: "I suspect max_locks_per_transaction won't tune nothing." -- uh, why would you suspect that? Have you tried actually following the hint's suggestion?

Comment: _Have you tried actually following the hint's suggestion?_ I have uncommented `max_locks_per_transaction = 64 # min 10` in /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf so far.

Comment: The default max_locks_per_transaction is 64 to begin with - uncommenting that line didn't effectively change it.

Comment: OK an effective increase to 128 _solved the issue_, actually allowed the operation to continue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your comment about intensive dropping and creating and the notice you received regarding increasing max_locks_per_transaction hint that you're dropping and creating many objects **in the same transaction**. Each of those results in a lock, which each requires a small amount of shared memory. Because of this, max_locks_per_transaction limits the number of locks you can hold within a transaction (to prevent any one transaction from using all of shared memory).

You could either increase that limit a bit (I would recommend against setting it arbitrarily large or you will run in to a separate situation of actually running out of total shared memory) or do your drops and creates either in batches of transactions or as one drop/create per transaction.

Edit: Apparently I was wrong about how max_locks_per_transaction works. From the documentation, the total number of locks available is max_locks_per_transaction * (max_connections + max_prepared_transactions) - any one transaction may hold more than max_locks_per_transaction, as long as the number of locks held everywhere is less than this total value.

Comment: My workflow includes (1) dumping a schema X, (2) dropping another schema Y, and (3) restoring X on the schema name Y. As I told, until today I've been over several weeks performing these activities, and today the step (2) is failing. Step (2) mainly consists on `DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS public CASCADE; CREATE SCHEMA public`, these are the sentences throwing the WARNING, ERROR and HINT.

Comment: Doubling the max locks from 64 to 128 allowed the workflow to continue. Ivn't got all the internals yet, but I guess committing between the DROP SCHEMA and the CREATE SCHEMA sentences will have a similar relieving effect.

Comment: Now I realize many days I get a small schema increase, and this issue perfectly matches one of those _small schema increases_. As a general strategy I will have greater consideration with HINTs from now on.